# VBA Color Cells Depending on the value

Tags: vba, colors

I would like to color cells depending on their value. If the value is 0, the cell should be green, if 1 then red. The whole thing should be a progression so the closer the value is to 1 the redder the cell should be.

Is there a suitable function for this?

Many thanks:)

My current solution looks like that but its not very pretty;)

```
Cells(i, 20) = (l / j) * 1 
        
Cells(i, 20).Interior.Color = RGB(255 * (l / j), 255 * (1 - (l / j)), 0)
```

Comment: Conditional Formatting? Is that what you should use instead of VBA?

Comment: I would prefer a solution using VBA as I create a new Workbook everytime. But thank you:)

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Think it makes more sense to use conditional formatting for this, but the code below produces the results in the picture.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range

For Each r In Range("A1:A11")
    r.Interior.Color = RGB(255 * r.Value, 255 * (1 - r.Value), 0)
Next r

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I'm 100% with you, using conditional formating fit better (update of colors at the same time than value + working using .xls file). Nice pieces of code by the way
Bye !